# How to add pagination using angular js in datatable

Tags: angularjs, datatables

**How to add pagination using angular js in jquery Datatable plugin. There is some external plugin available like angular js data table that directly allows pagination but i want to make inside jquery data table. **

```js
var app= angular.module("myModule",['ui-bootstrap']);

app.controller("dataController",function($scope,$http){

 $http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/833qv'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
 $scope.employees=response.data;
 console.log($scope.employees);
    
  });
   
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Angula js | Home </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-app="myModule">
  
  <input type="text" ng-model="searchFilter" />
  <div ng-controller="dataController">
    <table style="width:500px;border:2px solid black;">
      <thead>
        <tr style="text-align:left;">
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Client name</th>
          <th>Client code</th>
          <th>Team id</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
          <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
          <td>{{employee.client_name}}</td>
          <td>{{employee.client_code}}</td>
          <td>{{employee.team_id}}</td>
        </tr> 

      </tbody>
    </table>
 
  </div> 
 </div>

  

  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

its not accepting datatable pagination. can it possible that angular js accept datatable jqyery pagination.

Comment: what is in response.data ?

Comment: you can use [dir-pagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) to apply pagination

Answer (score 1):

Pagination:

HTML part

```
        <ul>
            <li class="paginationclass" style="font-weight:bold;"><span>Name</span><span>Age</span><span>Designation</span></li>            
 <li class="paginationclass" ng-repeat="datalist in datalists | pagination: curPage * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize">
     <div><span>{{ datalist.name }} </span><span>{{ datalist.age }}</span><span>{{ datalist.designation }}</span></div> 
 </li>
</ul> 

    <div class="pagination pagination-centered" ng-show="datalists.length">
<ul class="pagination-controle pagination">
 <li>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="curPage == 0"
 ng-click="curPage=curPage-1"> &lt; PREV</button>
 </li>
 <li>
 <span>Page {{curPage + 1}} of {{ numberOfPages() }}</span>
 </li>
 <li>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
 ng-disabled="curPage >= datalists.length/pageSize - 1"
 ng-click="curPage = curPage+1">NEXT &gt;</button>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>



    </div>
</div>
```

JS part

```
var myapp = angular.module('sampleapp', [ ]);

myapp.controller('samplecontoller', function ($scope) {


 $scope.showData = function( ){

 $scope.curPage = 0;
 $scope.pageSize = 3;
     $scope.datalists = [
         { "name": "John","age":"16","designation":"Software Engineer1"},
    {"name": "John2","age":"21","designation":"Software Engineer2"},
    {"name": "John3","age":"19","designation":"Software Engineer3"},
    {"name": "John4","age":"17","designation":"Software Engineer4"},
    {"name": "John5","age":"21","designation":"Software Engineer5"},
    {"name": "John6","age":"31","designation":"Software Engineer6"},
    {"name": "John7","age":"41","designation":"Software Engineer7"},
    {"name": "John8","age":"16","designation":"Software Engineer8"},
    {"name": "John18","age":"16","designation":"Software Engineer9"},
    {"name": "John28","age":"16","designation":"Software Engineer10"},
    {"name": "John38","age":"16","designation":"Software Engineer11"},
    {"name": "John48","age":"16","designation":"Software Engineer12"},
    {"name": "John58","age":"16","designation":"Software Engineer13"},
    {"name": "John68","age":"16","designation":"Software Engineer14"},
    {"name": "John68","age":"16","designation":"Software Engineer15"}
]
     $scope.numberOfPages = function() {
                return Math.ceil($scope.datalists.length / $scope.pageSize);
            };

}

});

angular.module('sampleapp').filter('pagination', function()
{
 return function(input, start)
 {
  start = +start;
  return input.slice(start);
 };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this code not working in my code.Kindly create a jsfiddle or add running code.

Comment: @VISHALSINGH  here is the working demo of [dir-paginate](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview)

Comment: @Tajinder-thanks for demo but if you create a simple demo , this demo having dirpagination.js file that is hard to understand for me.

Comment: @VISHALSINGH have you found any solution?

Comment: @VISHALSINGH what kind of sample do you require? do you need sample of dir-pagination?

Comment: you are adding long js for pagination, that i also find out on google. but i want short way so i understand flow and easily implement in my project.

Comment: Please check this fiddle [Pagination](http://jsfiddle.net/prash/Cp73s/330/).Hope you find it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use this open source library basically enhanced version of JQuery DataTables to rendered tables which include pagination, sorting, searching and filtering and very good support of accessibility.
    https://assets.cms.gov/resources/framework/2.0/Pages/datatables.html.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this code not working in my code.Kindly create a jsfiddle or add running code